# How to trace a JSP

Tags: jsp, trace

Is there any way to trace a JSP to determine where it's giving me an error. I get a java.lang.NullPointerException, but I have no idea which part of the code is causing it. Is there any statement I can use to trace where the error occurs?

Comment: can you give whole errortrace ?

Answer (score 0):

Look at these links.

http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/initial-contribution/IBM/evalGuides/ServerToolsEval.html

[debug JSP from eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123462/debug-jsp-from-eclipse)

Comment: I'm using it with oracle, plsql, etc. so I don't think that will be possible

Comment: using jsp with oracle, plsql? What is your app server to render your jsp?

Answer (score 0):

Look for the corresponding .java file and set a break point in that at the line throwing the NPE.

A JSP gets compiled to a .java file, before being passed to javac for compilation.

Comment: The oracle process does not seem to keep the .java files. I can find the .class file but not the .java. So no luck there.

Comment: Which Servlet Container are you using ?

Comment: Ok - so you need to work out how to ensure that the intermediary .java files are not deleted. This will be setting you can set on the web server. BTW - Apache is not a servlet container. I am not sure what iAS is.