# Debugging Custom java WebApplication

Tags: java

I have IVR -Java application deployed on caucho Resin server
Web App is not in server but directory outside on same system. Also Jsp are getting compiled in external directory.
In eclipse I have source code when I launch debugger I am able to connect and I am able to debug through java classes but when control goes to jsp file it is not able to find source

Any idea how i can fix it.??

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that's because eclipse can't find the source. Have you tried adding that to the build path? Project -> properties   search for build path.

If the source requires a different language to run, Jsp (i've never dealt with that), then perhaps you can get a plugin for eclipse for that language (jsp) and then add the jsp source to a (eclipse) project that houses the jsp section of the whole project.

Edit: seems like since I haven't messed with JSP much, I gave the wrong advice. Follow the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123462/debug-jsp-from-eclipse) in the comment below.

Comment: build path? Jsp are getting compiled into work folder and application is working also i am nt able to see it through eclipse to debug