# How to expand all nodes in the Variables View in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, debugging, variables

I'm attempting to use Eclipse to debug a JSP page. Have set breakpoints and would like to know the current value of a couple of variables, e.g. this one:

```
<c:set var="flows" value="${model.flows}" />
```

However, [hovering over doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123462/debug-jsp-from-eclipse#123777) so am attempting to use the Variables View, which looks like:

[image: Variables View]

Each one of these has a complex tree structure so finding what I need isn't obvious. Is there a quick way to expand all the nodes in the tree without lots of mouse clicking? Or search the whole tree?

Comment: From what I remember from when I used eclipse, there is no expand all button when you are in the variable view. There is only a collapse all.

Comment: I guess the eclipse developers have not implemented it yet because of cyclic dependencies between objects. How should an expand all work with cyclic dependencies? Where to stop?

Comment: @RenéLink That would be a good explanation as to why it is not implemented.

Comment: I also found this in the eclipse wiki: http://wiki.eclipse.org/Expand_Selected_Variables_Button_in_Debug

Comment: @RenéLink Fair point but you'd think there might be a way, e.g. stop beyond a certain number of levels or after a certain number of repetitions...

Comment: @SteveChambers yes I agree. What you said is also what is proposed in the wiki entry I posted. Maybe there is more to consider. I have to think about it for a while. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fought with the same problem in eclipse. Without finding a short and easy solution I decided to overwrite the `toString` method for all of my objects.
That gaves me the possibility to get a String representation with the most important data inside the `Variables tab` of the `debug mode` without step into the complex tree structure.
Of course that solution has a high effort but if it is done once the troubleshooting is much easier.

Comment: You don't have to override the `toString` method just for debugging purposes. You can use a `Detail Formatter`. Just right click on a variable and choose `New Detail Formatter...`.

Comment: PS: A `Detail Formatter` is also useful for third party libraries when you can not override the `toString` method.

Comment: @René Link: Nice dont know that. Nevertheless I think to overwrite the toString method is always a good approach